# Concurrency on Remote Machines for R

Tags: r, concurrency

I am using R for classification. To increase concurrency I am using doMC package.

```
> library(doMC)
> registerDoMC(cores = 4)
> model <- train(y~., data=trainingData, method="rf")
```

Is there any R package where I can use remote machines' CPU.

Comment: This [CRAN task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) should have relevant information.

Comment: As does our [survey paper on R and parallel computing](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i01/) referenced in the [HPC Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html). Neither one would have been particularly hard to find by either Google search or a search here on SO.